# How to run Multiple Queries and result store in multiple csv files

Tags: php, mysql, csv

how to run mysql query and output the results in csv. i know the solution should be like this:

```
SELECT col1,col2,col3
 FROM my_table
 INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/orders.csv'
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
 ENCLOSED BY '"'
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

But my problem is,i have approx 15 queries and i want to run all 15 query and results store in multiple csv files.currently for first query it's working fine and create the csv file.but not creates the csv for other queries.Please Help :)

Query1

```
SELECT CE.ENTITY_ID 'CUSTOMER ID'
 ,CE.EMAIL 'CUSTOMER EMAIL ADDRESS'
 ,CE.CREATED_AT
 ,CE.UPDATED_AT
 ,CE.IS_ACTIVE
 ,CE.STORE_ID
 ,(SELECT VALUE
      FROM CUSTOMER_ENTITY_VARCHAR CEV1
      WHERE CEV1.ATTRIBUTE_ID = 1 
      AND CEV1.ENTITY_ID = CE.ENTITY_ID) AS 'FIRST NAME'
 ,CEV.VALUE AS 'LAST NAME'
FROM CUSTOMER_ENTITY CE, CUSTOMER_ENTITY_VARCHAR CEV
WHERE CE.ENTITY_ID = CEV.ENTITY_ID
     AND CEV.ATTRIBUTE_ID = 2
INTO OUTFILE '$localDrive/DIM_CUSTOMER.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '`'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'";
```

Query2

```
SELECT LC.LOG_ID
 ,LC.VISITOR_ID
 ,LC.CUSTOMER_ID
 ,LC.LOGIN_AT
 ,LC.LOGOUT_AT
 ,LVI.HTTP_REFERER 'REFERRER SOURCE URL'
 ,LVI.HTTP_USER_AGENT
 ,LVI.HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE
 ,LVI.REMOTE_ADDR 
FROM LOG_CUSTOMER LC, LOG_VISITOR_INFO LVI
WHERE LVI.VISITOR_ID = LC.VISITOR_ID
INTO OUTFILE '$localDrive/AGG CUSTOMER LOGIN.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '`'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'";
```

******************************************Solved***********************************************

> Actual error is the way i execute the query.correct way is given below:

```
$db->exec($query)
```

that's it and it solve my problem:

Comment: I dont think its possible, you can output only one file per query

Comment: Do you want to create the files in parallel or serially? If you show the code which does not produce the other files, that would help.

Comment: @Saqueib ya i have 15 different query.i want to get output of all queries data in different csv files.right now only 1 query gives and output as a csv file.

Comment: @Tony see my updated question.my first query gives csv but second query not gives any csv.i want csv for both query

Comment: Do you get any error message for the second query? And what is in the "$localDrive" variable? `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` will write to the _server_ file system, not to your local machine.

Comment: @Tony no i am not getting any error. "$localDrive" variable containing the path of my directory like "C:/temp/".for 1st query i'm getting csv in this path but not for second query.

Comment: @Tony hey!!! i find the solution.see my updated question

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution. Post your answer as an Answer below (you are allowed to answer your own questions on SO) and then, after waiting a bit, mark it as resolved. So that others know you have a solution.

Comment: @Tony :hey i posted my solution.thanks for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actual error is the way i execute the query.correct way is given below:

```
$db->exec($query);
```

that's it and it solve my problem: